# Phonegap Filetransfer works on iOS nothing happens on Android

Tags: android, ios, cordova, file-transfer

Now, I have a problem with uploading some images on the server. My code works perfectly on iOS devices, but when I'm trying to upload on Android, it just doesn't do anything. Before the filetransfer, I'm trying to alert the ImageURI, but it's not happening as well.

I'm using PhoneGap Build with Phonegap version 3.4.0 and Sencha Touch 2.3. In the config.xml I use the core phonegap camera plugin:  `<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.camera" />.`

My fileupload script looks like this:

```
Ext.define('my_app.controller.Fileupload', {
    extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
    requires: [
        'Ext.MessageBox'
    ],
    config: {
        refs: {
            fileupload: '#fileupload',
            getLibraryImage: 'button[action=getLibraryImage]',
            getCameraImage: 'button[action=getCameraImage]'
        },
        control: {
            getLibraryImage: {
                tap: 'getLibraryImage'
            },
            getCameraImage: {
                tap: 'getCameraImage'
            }
        }
    },
    getLibraryImage: function() {

        navigator.camera.getPicture(this.fileupload, onFail, {
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY,
            allowEdit: true,
            targetWidth: 800,
            targetHeight: 800
        });

        function onFail(message) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }

    },
    getCameraImage: function() {

        navigator.camera.getPicture(this.fileupload, onFail, {
            destinationType: Camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
            quality: 100,
            allowEdit: true,
            targetWidth: 800,
            targetHeight: 800
        });

        function onFail(message) {
            alert('Failed because: ' + message);
        }

    },
    fileupload: function(imageURI) {

    alert(imageURI);

        Ext.Viewport.setMasked({
            xtype: 'loadmask',
            message: Loc.t('LOADMASK.FILEUPLOAD'),
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            indicator: true
        });

        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey = "file";
        options.fileName = imageURI.substr(imageURI.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);
        options.mimeType = "image/jpeg";

//  if (Ext.os.is('Android')) {
//      options.chunkedMode = true;
//  }

        var user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

        var user_id = user.id;
        var username = user.username;

        var params = new Object();
        params.user_id = user_id;
        params.username = username;
        options.params = params;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(imageURI, encodeURI("my_upload_uri"), win, fail, options);

        function win(response) {

            if (Ext.JSON.decode(response.response).error) {

                Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);
                Ext.Msg.alert('my_app', Ext.JSON.decode(response.response).error);

            } else {


                my_app.app.getController('Basic').ProfileImages();
                Ext.Msg.alert('my_app', Ext.JSON.decode(response.response).success);


            }


        }

        function fail(error) {

            Ext.Viewport.setMasked(false);

            alert("An error has occurred: Code = " + error.code);
        }

    }
});
```

If anyone can see the problem, I'd really appreciate the help! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by upgrading to PhoneGap version 3.6.3.